# Why is my callback suddendly failing for angular app using Auth0 deployed on heroku?

Tags: angular, authentication, heroku, content-security-policy

The authentication feature using Auth0 was working great then recently started showing, "Cannot GET /callback".

The callback url is whitelisted in my Auth0 dashboard.
The `callbackUrl` is also set to the correct uri, for example `myapp.heroku.com/callback` .

What would cause this to randomly stop working? In the console I see a content security error

`Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”).`

I suspect this could be the culprit but I’m not sure how to solve this.

Has anybody experienced this before?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I am having trouble after moving to prod mode on Heroku with the callback...it says asdf.heroku.com/callback#accesstoken not found

Comment: Did you get the solution to this? I am facing the same issue but with Auth0, Vue,js and Heroku as the stack.